# SSIS Row Count Not Populating

Tags: .net, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2008

quick question:

I am having an issue with trying to get a row count in a data flow task. I have tried both a Row Count transform as well as a script task custom count and both are yielding the same result. I have a variable called "ETLRowCount" which is not an expression, and set to 0. When trying to use both either the row count or setting the variable in a script task, it just stays at 0.

On the right side of the picture below, I am inserting the row count into an auditing table just as a test because we are running into duplicate record issues (It's a crappy access database source, the left side of the picture is the normal etl record insert), but I keep getting 0. It is like it is just not counting the rows and recording it. I know for a fact there are rows being inserted because the ETL table has 10k rows after each run on the job (it gets truncated first). Any ideas? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: can you add the script code and a screenshot of the variables tab/window?? Also please add the sql you are using to extract the data if any. Beside this, you can also add extra screenshots showing the execution of the data flow.

Answer (score 0):

I just read that a variable doesn't get populated until after the DFT so I can't use it in the same task.